# Calculate roots of multiple polynomials

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math

Given a matrix `A` that represents polynomials in each column. How can the roots of each polynomial be calculated efficiently without loops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a comparison between 3 methods:

1. A simple loop through all the rows, using `roots` on each row.
2. A completely loopless approach, based on YBE's idea of using a block-diagonal matrix, 
   using `sparse` as an intermediate
3. A simple loop through all the rows, but this time using "inlined" code from `roots`.

The code:

```
%// The polynomials
m = 15;
n = 8;
N = 1e3;

X = rand(m,n);


%// Simplest approach
tic
for mm = 1:N

    R = zeros(n-1,m);
    for ii = 1:m
        R(:,ii) = roots(X(ii,:));
    end

end
toc


%// Completely loopless approach
tic
for mm = 1:N

    %// Indices for the scaled coefficients
    ii = repmat(1:n-1:m*(n-1), n-1,1);
    jj = 1:m*(n-1);

    %// Indices for the ones
    kk = bsxfun(@plus, repmat(2:n-1, m,1), (n-1)*(0:m-1).');  %'
    ll = kk-1;

    %// The block diagonal matrix
    coefs = -bsxfun(@rdivide, X(:,2:end), X(:,1)).';  %'
    one   = ones(n-2,m);
    C = full(sparse([ii(:); kk(:)], [jj(:); ll(:)],...
        [coefs(:); one(:)]));

    %// The roots
    R = reshape(eig(C), n-1,m);

end
toc


%// Simple loop, roots() "inlined"
tic    
R = zeros(n-1,m);
for mm = 1:N

    for ii = 1:m            
        A = zeros(n-1);
        A(1,:) = -X(ii,2:end)/X(ii,1);
        A(2:n:end) = 1;
        R(:,ii) = eig(A);            
    end

end
toc
```

The results:

```
%// m=15, n=8, N=1e3:
Elapsed time is 0.780930 seconds. %// loop using roots()
Elapsed time is 1.959419 seconds. %// Loopless
Elapsed time is 0.326140 seconds. %// loop over inlined roots()

%// m=150, n=18, N=1e2:
Elapsed time is 1.785438 seconds. %// loop using roots()
Elapsed time is 110.1645 seconds. %// Loopless
Elapsed time is 1.326355 seconds. %// loop over inlined roots()
```

Of course, your mileage may vary, but the general message should be clear: The old advice of avoiding loops in MATLAB is just that: ***OLD***. It just no longer applies to MATLAB versions R2009 and up.

Vectorization can still be a good thing though, but certainly not always. As in this case: profiling will tell you that most time is spent on computing the eigenvalues for the block-diagonal matrix. The algorithm underlying `eig` scales as `N³` (yes, that is a *three*), plus it cannot take advantage of sparse matrices in any way (like this block-diagonal one), making the approach a poor choice in this particular context.

Loops are your friend here ^_^

Now, this is of course based on `eig()` of the companion matrix, which is a nice and simple method to compute all roots in one go. There are of course many more methods to compute roots of polynomials, each with their own advantages/disadvantages. Some are a lot faster, but aren't so good when a few of the roots are complex. Others are a lot faster, but need a fairly good initial estimate for every root, etc. Most other rootfinding methods are usually a lot more complicated, which is why I left these out here.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) is a nice overview, and [here](http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/16/1/mekwi.pdf) is a more in-depth overview, along with some MATLAB code examples.

If you're smart, you should only dive into this material if you need to do this computation millions of times on a daily basis for at least the next few weeks, otherwise, it's just not worth the investment.

If you're smarter, you'll recognize that this will undoubtedly come back to you at some point, so it's worthwhile to do anyway.

And if you're an academic, you master all the root-finding methods so you'll have a giant toolbox, so you can pick the best tool for the job whenever a new job comes along. Or even dream up your own method :)

Comment: Very nice analysis! +1.

Comment: I reckon you just saved me a few days of calculation time :D   Know anyway to speed up the combined task of finding the root of the derivative of the polynomial so you can find the max / min of the poly? Mostly only one root would then be important :/

Comment: @geometrikal: well, that would work the same way, but the coefficient matrix of the derivative would be `Cprime = (numel(C)-1:-1:1) .* C(1:end-1);`, where `C` are the coefficients of your original polynomial. By the way, what do you mean exactly with "combined task"?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I have to find that max of a complex polynomial. So I take the derivative, find the roots of that, then evaluate each root in the original polynomial to find the maximum. I just wonder if there is some speed up where the root that corresponds to the max comes out without having to waste time on the other roots. Alternatively do you know if there is a way to speed up eig by just evaluating the roots to a few significant figures? If so I will make it a question.

Comment: @geometrikal: That's starting to sound like optimization theory :) AFAIK, there is no known way for polynomials to know *beforehand* where the min/max will be. A few thoughts: 1) there is no maximum for polynomials of odd-degree, or for polynomials with positive real first coefficient, 2) a second-derivative test might save you a few computations, 3) `eigs()` allows better control over the accuracy, but is only fast for large, sparse problems -- profile to see if it suits your needs

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) in combination with [`roots`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/roots.html), which will give you the results in terms of cell arrays.

```
n = size(A,2);
t = arrayfun(@(x)roots(A(:,x)), 1:n, 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

You can then use [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) to convert it to a matrix. Either: `r = cell2mat(t)`, or

```
r = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)roots(A(:,x)), 1:n, 'UniformOutput', 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Practically what `roots` does is to find the eigenvalues of the companion matrix.

```
roots(p) = eig(compan(p))
```

So here is my example that constructs a block-diagonal matrix out of the companion matrices of each polynomial, than finds the eigenvalues of the block-diagonal matrix.

```
>> p1=[2 3 5 7];
>> roots(p1)

ans =

  -0.0272 + 1.5558i
  -0.0272 - 1.5558i
  -1.4455          

>> eig(compan(p1))

ans =

  -0.0272 + 1.5558i
  -0.0272 - 1.5558i
  -1.4455          

>> p2=[1 2 9 5];
>> roots(p2)

ans =

  -0.6932 + 2.7693i
  -0.6932 - 2.7693i
  -0.6135          

>> p3=[5 1 4 7];
>> roots(p3)

ans =

   0.3690 + 1.1646i
   0.3690 - 1.1646i
  -0.9381          

>> A=blkdiag(compan(p1),compan(p2),compan(p3))

A =

   -1.5000   -2.5000   -3.5000         0         0         0         0         0         0
    1.0000         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0    1.0000         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0   -2.0000   -9.0000   -5.0000         0         0         0
         0         0         0    1.0000         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0    1.0000         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0   -0.2000   -0.8000   -1.4000
         0         0         0         0         0         0    1.0000         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    1.0000         0

>> eig(A)

ans =

  -0.0272 + 1.5558i
  -0.0272 - 1.5558i
  -1.4455          
  -0.6932 + 2.7693i
  -0.6932 - 2.7693i
  -0.6135          
   0.3690 + 1.1646i
   0.3690 - 1.1646i
  -0.9381
```

Comment: What if there are 20, or 100 columns? Using `A=blkdiag(compan(p1),compan(p2),compan(p3),compain(p4),...)` is not a good approach.

Comment: Good start, although you'll still have to come up with a version that does this for arbitrary size `A`. Also, I'd use a sparse matrix, and reshape the output such that at least one dimension equals the number of polynomials.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis thanks. I just tried to illustrate the concept.

Comment: @RobertP.you are right it is not very efficient for big # of columns. Though for small number of columns it may be faster than `arrayfun`. Also I am not sure but MATLAB may exploit the the block-diagonal form of the matrix as well, that may be fast. Though that is just a hypothesis.

Comment: Maybe processing batches of 10 polynoms with this method is the fastest.